# How to make an adapter for a micro SIM?

Tags: substitute-tool, technology, phone

I currently have an iPhone 4S and these models use a 'micro-SIM' which is smaller than a standard SIM Card *(see below)*:

[image]

The thing is **I need to move the SIM from the iPhone *(micro-SIM)* into an older handset that is designed to take a normal sized SIM**.

As it is design to take a normal SIM it won't be able to securely hold the smaller micro-SIM so I was wondering if there is anything I can use to create an adapter that will allow me to use  a micro-SIM in place of a standard SIM.

*(Note: I am aware that there are adapters available but I do not have one and do not want to have to buy or obtain one. Plus I am interested in what other ways there could be to get around this problem!)*

A method that would also be adaptable to the even smaller '[nano-SIM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duRjx.jpg)' would be good!

Comment: Go to your mobile provider. They usually have such adapters in their shop. If you really don't want to get one (probably free) you could try crafting one your own using plastic or thin cardboard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get a thin piece of plastic. Cut it to a normal SIM size and shape and then cut a Micro SIM sized hole that will fit your SIM into it. This should now fit into your normal SIM phone easily - file it down if needed.

[image: used sim "card"]

[image: like this]

[image: done!]

Comment: WARNING: Don't do this yourself unless you have a 3D printer! The piece of plastic is now stuck in my mobile phone (Nokia N86) and I can't take it out. I opened the device and took the micro SIM card away but the plastic adapter can't go out. The last resort is probably to unsolder the SIM slot, hopefully it is an old device that I don't use anymore.

Answer (score 1):

When I had this situation, I was able to slide the micro-SIM into the correct position manually and tape it into place, but this depends on having a phone with an open SIM slot (e.g. under the battery rather than in the side edge of the phone) where it is possible to see the locations of the contacts clearly, and to remove the card later.