# How to convert standard SIM into Nano SIM?

Tags: technology, phone

I've some standard SIM cards which I'd like to test on my iPhone 5, but they're way too big.

Is there any adapter or methods of converting the SIM card, so it could fit and work into smaller Nano SIM plug?

It's similar to [make an adapter for a Micro SIM](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6251/how-to-make-an-adapter-for-a-micro-sim), but other way round.

Comment: This doesn't need an out-of-the-box solution. Cutting it down is a standard solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use an adapter as you can use sharp pair of scissors to cut it either to a micro-SIM or nano-SIM.

[image]

<sup>Image contribution: Google Images</sup>

[image: How to make Micro-SIM from usual SIM card]

<sup>Image contributions: [How to Get a Micro SIM?](http://www.chengduliving.com/forums/topic/how-to-get-a-micro-sim/)</sup>

In China they're using these kind of devices:

[image: China Mobile cut it for me the day I walked in for a SIM Card with one of these]

<sup>Image contributions: [How to Get a Micro SIM?](http://www.chengduliving.com/forums/topic/how-to-get-a-micro-sim/)</sup>

Related:

- (video) [How to cut your SIM card (Micro SIM, Nano SIM - iPhone 5)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6T1Mygucak) by Unbox Therapy
- (video) [How to Cut Standard SIM Card to Micro SIM Using Scissor](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzsOPfwR46w) by ITJungles
- [How To Convert a SIM to a MicroSIM with a Meat Cleaver!](http://www.solutios.com/simcutting/)
- [How to cut your own micro-SIM card](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-cut-your-own-micro-sim-card/) at cnet